# how do I set up a contextSwitch to generate a csv file

Tags: zend-framework

In my controller init method I have this

```
public function init()
{
    //initialise the context switch action helper
    $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch')
                  ->addContext('csv', array('suffix' => 'csv',
                                            'headers' => array(
                                                'Context-Type' => 'application/csv',
                                                'Context-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="fooo.csv"',
                                                'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
                                                'Expires' => '0',
                                            )))
                  ->addActionContext('stockreport', 'csv')
                  ->initContext();
}
```

In my stockreportAction I have disabled the layout and view render as follows.

```
public function stockreportAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    echo 'foobar';
}
```

I get a blank page when I call this file, I would like to generate this so in the example 'foobar' appears as a downloadable csv file. Could anyone advise

Answer (score -3):

Zend_Magic is not implemented yet.

It is your responsibility to generate csv or any other output format.

in short: context switcher modify view script suffix, so view script for your context is stockreport.csv.phtml (if csv context is active, stockreport.phtml otherwise).
But in your example context switcher used in a wrong way. You don't switch context here.
You don't use viewscripts, you don't check if context active in your action.

Why your output is empty is a different question - probably at some point you clear content in Response object or there somewhere is a fatal error & error output disabled.

**Update:**
Also headers are `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition`